# I'm a Power BI noob struggling to understand how bookmarks work

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

Our Power BI developer quit and I've inherited his applications.  The problem is I have no Power BI experience and am learning via trial by fire.  I've currently been tasked with adding some new fields to an app that's using bookmarking.  Below is a picture of my app, I added the # Student Grades cards under each score.  Users have the ability to see current Progress scores, end of Semester 1 scores, or end of Semester 2 scores.  As I understand it, that means I need to add the same card three times -- one for each view/bookmark, and then in the section grid hide/unhide the appropriate cards.  The issue I'm having is that when I'm ready to Update a bookmark, I'm clicking on the three ellipses next to the bookmark and selecting "Update". The issue though is that it makes that update to all the bookmarks!  Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong?

I'm using Power BI Desktop V2.108

Thanks in advance for any help you can give!!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

check if there is any Group in the bookmarks... also check the below `All Visuals` checked or not...

[image: all visuals]